# Ruby on Rails: Devise Gem Admin customization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, haml, admin

How can I run this code as a link or button in haml:

```
current_user.update_attribute :admin, true
```

I am trying to make it so there is a section of the site to make one an admin. This is a part of making admin accounts in devise from the wiki they have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wanted to share my solution for this. It seems to be nicest way to do it very quickly. I forgot to post it earlier:

I made my email essentially a master account that will always be an admin. Alternatively you can rake data into production to set a 1rst account. From there, any admin can set other admins! I added a boolean value called admin to the users model generated for Devise in order to set admins.

```
rails g migration AddAdminToUsers admin:boolean
```

admin_updater.html.haml

```
- if current_user.email == 'shravvmehtaa@gmail.com'
    = form_for :emails, url: make_admin_emails_path, :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f|
      .form-group
        %span
          %p{:style => "margin: 0px;"}
            = f.label :email, "Email:"
          %p{:style => "float: left;"}
            = f.text_field :email, :style=> "width: 200px;", :class => "form-control"
          %p{:style => "margin-left: 10px; float: left;"}
            = f.submit "Make Admin", :class => 'btn btn-success'
    = form_for :emails, url: delete_admin_emails_path, :html => {:class => "form-inline"} do |f|
      .form-group
        %span
          %p{:style => "margin: 0px;"}
            = f.label :email, "Email:"
          %p{:style => "float: left;"}
            = f.text_field :email, :style=> "width: 200px;", :class => "form-control"
          %p{:style => "margin-left: 10px; float: left;"}
            = f.submit "Delete Admin", :class => 'btn btn-danger'
    %b Admins:
    - @users = User.all
    - @users.each do |user|
      - if user.admin?
        %div{:style => "border: 2px solid black; background-color: white; padding: 5px; height: 63px; width: 400px; margin-bottom: 10px;"} 
          %span{:style => "float: left;"}  
            = image_tag (user.profile_pic)
          %span{:style => "float: left; margin-left: 10px;"}
            = user.name
            %br
            = link_to(user.email, "mailto:" + user.email)
```

Controller

```
class MemberController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]
  layout "dashboard"

  def make_admin
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:emails][:email])
    unless @user.nil?
      @user.update_attribute(:admin, true)
    end
    redirect_to '/dashboard/develop'
  end

  def delete_admin
    @user = User.find_by_email(params[:emails][:email])
    unless @user.nil?
      @user.update_attribute(:admin, false)
    end
    redirect_to '/dashboard/develop'
  end

end
```

This is the resulting output from the part of the code above. I personally integrated mine with Facebook, so I needed some quick code to grab email information and set admins after accounts were made:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to create a checkbox on your edit user form, which corresponds to the admin boolean model field.  Then, when your update action saves the User record, it will update the attribute by virtue of that field being included in the form:

```
-form_for @user do |f|
    %p
        = f.label :admin
        %br
        = f.check_box :admin
```

Naturally, you will need to restrict access to the update user form in some manner, so that only admins can see it. This is a separate issue, however. Hope this helps!

Comment: yes, that is my point. I have a page that only one account can see, and in that page I want a piece of code like this to run so that I can add admins!

Comment: Assuming that you are using conventional form handlers in rails, just adding the field to your form should allow that attribute to be updated via a simple User#update controller action. Unless I'm missing something. Could you share your view code perhaps?